# Racket R6RS support: syntax-case

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs

This simple R6RS program:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs syntax-case)
        (rnrs io simple))

(define-syntax stest
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
      ((_ z) #'(z 0)))))

(stest display)
```

works with Chez, Guile and Ypsilon but not Racket. It gives me this:

> test.scm:7:3: lambda: unbound identifier in the transformer
>   environment;
>   also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound

My question is, is it broken for R6RS or do I have to do something else? I'm testing with version 6.12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Racket implementation of R<sup>6</sup>RS is not non-compliant in this case. Indeed, if anything, it is obeying the standard more closely: your program as-written is not careful about import phases. The problem is that `define-syntax` evaluates its right-hand side during expand-time, as noted by section [11.2.2 Syntax definitions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/r6rs-std/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.2.2):

> Binds <keyword> to the value of <expression>, which must evaluate, at macro-expansion time, to a transformer.

Unlike other Scheme standards, R<sup>6</sup>RS takes care to distinguish between phases, since it permits arbitrary programming at compile-time (while other Scheme standards do not). Therefore, section [7.1 Library form](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/r6rs-std/r6rs-Z-H-10.html#node_sec_7.1) specifies how to import libraries at specific phases:

> Each <import spec> specifies a set of bindings to be imported into the library, the levels at which they are to be available, and the local names by which they are to be known. An <import spec> must be one of the following:
>
> ```
> <import set>
> (for <import set> <import level> ...)
> ```
>
> An <import level> is one of the following:
>
> ```
> run
> expand
> (meta <level>)
> ```
>
> where <level> represents an exact integer object.

Therefore, you need to import `(rnrs base)` at both the `run` and `expand` phases, and you need to import `(rnrs syntax-case)` at the expand phase. You can do this with the following program:

```
#!r6rs
(import (for (rnrs base) run expand)
        (for (rnrs syntax-case) expand)
        (rnrs io simple))

(define-syntax stest
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
      ((_ z) #'(z 0)))))

(stest display)
```

This program works in Racket. I have not tested if it also works on the other Scheme implementations you listed, but it ought to if they are standards-compliant.

Comment: Works with the other implementations as well. Awesome, thanks!